# coverpoint to check if 2 signals are active at the same time

Tags: system-verilog

I am trying to write a cover point to check where 2 signals should occurring at the same time or not.

```
covergroup signal@(posedge clk)
    signals : coverpoint (a, b){
    bins on_off = {2'b11}
}
```

I just wanted to know whether it is the correct path of writing the cover point.

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write `coverpoint {a,b}` using concatenation braces. That would work. Another thing you can do is

```
covergroup signal @(posedge clk);
    signals : coverpoint a&b {
    bins on = {1};
}
endgroup
```